# Trying X11 forwarding over ssh (to run Openbox) from Ubuntu server 18 to Windows/Putty

Tags: xorg, putty, openbox, xinerama

I have Ubuntu server running in Windows VMware (test install before going to independant hardware). Ubuntu has Openbox minimal interface installed/running.

I'm wanting to setup ssh for when this server is running headless on hardware.

On Win7 I've got Putty & XMing installed.

Rather than just a unix prompt, I thought I'd try forwarding X11 and hopefully run Openbox over ssh, or just a couple xterms if not.

OK so ssh terminal SEEMS to be forwarded: `echo $DISPLAY shows "localhost:10.0".`

My problem is that if I try to run Openbox on ssh prompt, I get these errors:

```
rhubear@neofs-vm:~$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
rhubear@neofs-vm:~$ openbox
Obt-Message: Xinerama extension is not present on the server
Openbox-Message: A window manager is already running on screen 0
```

(even if I exit openbox on the console, same error.)

I've tried to install Xinerama (packages below) but always get the above error.

```
rhubear@neofs-vm:~$ dpkg-query -l | grep xinerama*
ii  libxcb-xinerama0:amd64                1.13-2~ubuntu18.04                              amd64        X C Binding, xinerama extension
ii  libxcb-xinerama0-dev:amd64            1.13-2~ubuntu18.04                              amd64        X C Binding, xinerama extension, development files
ii  libxinerama-dev:amd64                 2:1.1.3-1                                       amd64        X11 Xinerama extension library (development headers)
ii  libxinerama1:amd64                    2:1.1.3-1                                       amd64        X11 Xinerama extension library
ii  x11proto-xinerama-dev                 2018.4-4                                        all          transitional dummy package
rhubear@neofs-vm:~$
```

If I try to run x-terminal-emulator in ssh, it pops up in the console, not in Windows or ssh window.  (not sure where Xming is supposed to show/generate a local/Win X11 content).

---

So my question is... Do I really need xinerama, or is that error message sidetracking me from another solution to forwarding X11 properly?

I've read that xinerama is more used to multiple hardware displays, which I'm NOT using here.  Just wanting some sort of X11 on SSH.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've done more testing here, and I've found that apps like xclock that (apparently) are not tied to Openbox ARE opened in Windows.

I tried installing a couple other (non Openbox?) terminals; xterm & xvt.  These BOTH are displayed on Windows.  So X11 forwarding is DEF working.

I'm gonna close this topic, and open another one regarding Openbox specifically - displaying Openbox through ssh.